# Why is text color in TextView in my widget white?

Tags: android, android-widget

Currently I am learning about widget in Android. Previously I tried to implement a widget in my dummy project and I could show TextView in black color. But, now I have another project and I implemented widget with the same way. I can show the text in the widget, but the problem is the color of the text is white while I use white background. I don't think I modify something in my previous project which made text to be black. Am I miss something here, something like passing the wrong `Context` maybe?

Widget Item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

RemoteViewsService:

```
public class WidgetItemService extends RemoteViewsService {

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return new ItemFactory();
    }

    class ItemFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

        private List<String> mStrings;

        public IngredientItemFactory() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDataSetChanged() {

            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(StringContract.StringEntry.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            mStrings = CursorUtils.extract(c);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mStrings.size();
        }

        @Override
        public RemoteViews getViewAt(int pos) {
            String string = mStrings.get(pos);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_text, string);

            return views;
        }

        @Override
        public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

AppWidgetProvider:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId: appWidgetIds) {
            String string = PrefUtils.load(this, appWidgetId);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetItemService.class);

            views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.lv_list, intent);
            views.setEmptyView(R.id.lv__list, R.id.tv_empty);

            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_title, string);

            Intent openActivity = BActivity.createIntent(string);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            PrefUtils.delete(context, appWidgetId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the theme of your new project.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
```

I find the `style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"`.

I clicked in.It was this.

```
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_body_1_material</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

So you can look at `android:textColorPrimary`.

Then,you look at the `theme color`.

Comment: everything looks just fine. In the end I apply `android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"` manually.

Comment: @Sam  `android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary` was the color of the Toolbar font.So you can check it.